# An English question for a logical term

Tags: terminology

Consider a tuple of logical expressions: $(P_1, \ldots, P_n)$ such that $P_i\Rightarrow P_{i+1}$ for every $i=1,\ldots,n-1$.

An English question: Should I call it *implications tuple* or *tuple of implications*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a chain of implications in English](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840867/writing-a-chain-of-implications-in-english)

Comment: If you want to choose the shorter form, I suggest that "implication tuple" would be a bit more idiomatic, even though it may look peculiar to you.

Answer (score 2):

Neither term exists, so define it however you like. A google search yields **zero** results for *implications tuple* and merely **three** for *tuple of implications*.

One of those results is [another Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840867/writing-a-chain-of-implications-in-english) regarding a chain of implications, which I now see you yourself started.

Comment: Well, be fair, the three google results are: this thread, the other thread you linked to, and a paper which has the exact phrase "...depend only on the presence, in the **tuple, of implications**...". It looks like no one uses the term "tuple of implications", per se.

Comment: @AlexNelson Thank you. So, both definitions are equally "not used".